# Is it possible to use DISTINCT in a mysql UDF?

Tags: mysql, distinct, user-defined-functions

How does mysql implement the `DISTINCT` keyword with its own aggregate functions? Can it be used in a UDF in the same way?

```
SELECT MY_UDF(DISTINCT value) FROM table
```

If so, does MySQL apply the DISTINCT before passing a group of rows to the UDF, or does the UDF itself have to handle it? And what happens with UDFs that take more than one argument? Does it distinct the whole tuple of inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried, and in MySQL, including the DISTINCT keyword in a UDF call is a syntax error. So I think it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it can be used in UDF in the same way as it is used in following statements.**

```
CREATE TABLE  sample_1 (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `col_val` int(11) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO sample_1(col_val) values (1),(1), (2),(3) ;

SELECT * FROM sample_1;

SELECT DISTINCT COL_VAL FROM sample_1;

SELECT SUM(DISTINCT COL_VAL) FROM sample_1;
```

Comment: That's an example using SUM, one of mysql's own aggregate functions. I'm asking about a user-defined function (an extension written by the user in c). Do you know anything about that? I've updated my question with a few more specific questions.